# Can the SQL Server Service Broker converse with a service in a web server (IIS) application?

Tags: sql-server-2005, service-broker

Is there any way to communicate to application components within the Web Server.  My application is made up of a Web Application on IIS 7.0 and a database on SQL Server 2005.  I have several satellite services that are poling the database, and I am wanting to replaces these with web services that are triggered from the SQL database itself.

Can the Service Broker do this?  Can it send start a conversation with a service within the web server (i.e. an ASP.Net page, a web service, or even a WCF service)?

**Edits:**

Is there any way that SQL server can call a web application component (i.e. web service, ASP.Net page. etc...).  I need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the form of "Query Notifications" which builds on Service Broker

I haven't done it myself but this page on MSDN shows you a few options and further link

["Query Notifications in SQL Server (ADO.NET)"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx)

As I understand it, there is no direct Service Broker API and it's done via SQL commands. 
Hence the use of SQLDependency or SQLNotificationRequest in .net not Service Broker directly. This article explains more http://javiercrespoalvez.com/2009/03/using-sql-service-broker-in-net.html